# How can I get rid of the empty interface used for a property

Tags: c#, interface, attributes

I have a class representing sensors in a plant. For historical reasons, similar objects (that are therefore represented by the same class) have a different identification:

- Some have a name (ie. "north-west-gummy-bear")
- Some have an areaId, and a sensorId

In order to accomodate for this, I use an empty interface:

```
public class sensor
{
    ISensorIdentifier id{get;set;}
}

public interface ISensorIdentifier{

}


public class namedSensorID:ISensorIdentifier{
    string name{get;set;}
}

public class idSensorID:ISensorIdentifier{
    int areaID{get;set;}
    int sensorID{get;set;}
}
```

This allows me to use the same class for objects with a different identification system.

It is my understanding that empty interfaces are a code smell, and that I should use custom attributes instead.

However, after reading about custom attributes, I have no idea where to start. Indeed, I could use a custom attribute 'sensorIdentifier' instead of the empty interface, but how should I type the `id` property in the `sensor` class?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can consider that a sensor has one unique valid identifier information (using c#7 native tuple support):

```
(Name, AreaId, SensorId)
```

Your business logic should enforce that valid id information must be:

```
(Name, null, null)
```

Or

```
(null, AreaId, SensorId)
```

Anything else is not valid. Ok, lets build a base class that enforces this:

```
public abstract class Sensor
{
     private readonly string name;
     private readonly int? areaId, sensorId;

     protected Sensor(string name)
     {
         this.name = name;
     }

     protected Sensor(int areaId, int sensorId)
     {
         this.areaId = areaId;
         this.sensorId = sensorId;
     }

     public (string Name, int? AreaId, int? SensorId) Id
     {
          get
          {
              Debug.Assert(
                  (name != null && !(areaId.HasValue || sensorId.HasValue)) ||
                  (name == null && (areaId.HasValue && sensorId.HasValue)));
              return (name, areaId, sensorId);
          }
     }
}
```

Your specific sensor implementations are trivial, extending `Sensor`:

```
public class NamedSensor: Sensor
{
    public NamedSensor(string name)
        :base(name)
    { }
}

public class IdSensor: Sensor
{
    public IdSensor(int areaId, int sensorId)
        :base(areaId, sensorId)
    { }
}
```

And you can happily work with an `IEnumerable<Sensor>`.

Comment: And for lower versions, just use a custom type to represent the id.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you add a unique identifier in your empty interface which should be implemented in each of your concrete classes:

```
public interface ISensorIdentifier
{
    string UniqueSensorId { get; }
}
```

You should simply ensure that these implementations in the different sub classes make this new ID unique. Here is a quick proposal:

```
public class namedSensorID : ISensorIdentifier
{
    public string UniqueSensorId { get { return nameof(namedSensorID) + name; } }

    string name { get; set; }
}

public class idSensorID : ISensorIdentifier
{

    int areaID { get; set; }
    int sensorID { get; set; }
    public string UniqueSensorId { get { return nameof(idSensorID) + areaID + sensorID; } }
}
```